In printing mode to make a div be at bottom of my page and on the last page of my printing
I have certification system management and I want to show a footer or a section at the bottom of my page on the last page.
I tried to fix the section but it shows on all pages.
I tried some javascript codes but it still gave me the problem.
Example of how I want to stick the selected red area to be in the yellow era and only show it on the last page in the footer but not show it in all pages

I want to print the signature on the last page and at the bottom of the page.
I have tried to fix it with javascript or CSS but I was not able to solve this problem.


@media print {
  .non-print-view {
    display: none;
  }
  footer {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px 1cm;
    background-color: #c2c3c5;
  }
  .for-print {
    display: block;
  }
  @page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0mm;
  }
  .watermark {
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    opacity: 0.1 !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    max-width: 440px;
    max-height: 540px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
  .qrCode {
    align-self: end;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
  }
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'AKFont';
  src: url("{{ asset('assets/fonts/public/assets/fonts/arabic.ttf') }}");
}


/* --------------- Start: Signature --------------- */

.signature {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2cm 1cm;
  padding: 1cm 0;
}

.signature h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.signature p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/withMarks.css') }}">
    <title>Certification
        @if (isset($student))
            {{ $student->name }}
        @endif
    </title>
</head>

<body style="position: relative;">
    <button class="non-print-view btn btn-primary">
        <a href="{{ route('admin.students') }}">زڤرین</a>
    </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="printView()" id="printButton" class="non-print-view btn btn-primary">
        چاپكرن
    </button>
    <section id="printSection">
        @php
            $head = 10;
            $mark = 0.6; // init value
            $noteSpace = 0.4;
            $otherMargin = 5;
            $totalSpace = $head;
            $break = true;
        @endphp
        <header class="container">
            <div class="header-left">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/logo.png') }}" alt="">
                <div>
                    <h1>زانـکـۆیـا دهـوك</h1>
                    <p>رێڤەبەریا تومارکرنا گشتی</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="header-right">
                کومارا ئیراقێ، هەرێما کوردستانێ <br>
                سەروکاتیا جڤاتا وەزیران <br>
                وەزارەتا خواندنێن باڵا و ڤەکولینێت زانستی
            </div>
        </header>

        <section class="transcript-head container">

            <div class="transcript-head-date">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="row-head">ژمارە: </div>

                    @php
                        $englishLettersToArabic = [
                            'B' => 'ب',
                            'M' => 'م',
                            'D' => 'د',
                            'C' => 'چ',
                        ];
                        $newCertificateUniqueId = strtr($certificate->certificate_unique_id, $englishLettersToArabic);
                    @endphp

                    <div>{{ $newCertificateUniqueId }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="row-head">مێژوو: </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>{{ date('Y/m/d') }} م</span>
                        <span>{{ getKurdishYear('ku') }} ك</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {{-- <div class="transcript-head-title">
                <h2>بەلگەناما نمرا</h2>
            </div> --}}
            <div class="transcript-head-image">
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/photos/students/' . $student->image) }}" alt="">
            </div>

        </section>


        <section class="transcript container">
            <h2>بەلگەناما نمرا</h2>
            @if (isset($transcript))
                @if (str_contains($transcript, $student->getNameByLang('ku')))
                    {!! str_replace(
                        $student->getNameByLang('ku'),
                        '<strong>' . $student->getNameByLang('ku') . '</strong>',
                        $transcript,
                    ) !!}
                @endif
            @endif
        </section>


        <section class="marks container">
            @foreach ($StudentSubjects as $year => $courses)
                @if ($loop->iteration > 2 && $loop->iteration % 2 == 1 || $loop->iteration > 3 && $loop->iteration % 6 == 0)
                    <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
                <script>
                    var header = document.querySelector('.transcript-head');
                    header.style.paddingTop = '2cm';

                     
                </script>
                @endif
                {{-- <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
                @endif --}}
                @php
                    // Determine the number of subjects for each course
                    $subjectsCounts = array_map('count', $courses);
                    $maxRows = max($subjectsCounts); // Find the course with the most subjects
                @endphp
                {{-- {{var_dump($totalSpace >= 16, $totalSpace)}}
                @if ($totalSpace >= 27 && $break)
                    <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
                    @php $break = false; @endphp
                    <div style="padding-top: 1cm;"></div>
                @endif --}}
                <h3>سالا
                    {{ numToText($loop->iteration, 'krd') }} {{changeYearToDoubleYear($year)}}</h3>

                @if (count($courses) == 2)
                    <div class="mark-row">
                @endif

                @foreach ($courses as $course => $subjects)
                    @php
                        $totalSpace += count($subjects) * $mark;
                    @endphp
                    <div>
                        <h4> وەرزێ {{ numToText($loop->iteration, 'krd') }}</h4>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <th>بابه‌ت</th>
                                <th>ژمارا یه‌كا</th>
                                <th>ب هەژمار</th>
                                <th>ب نڤیسین</th>
                                <th>پلە</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($subjects as $subject)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $subject['subject'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $subject['unit'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $subject['attempt'] == 1 ? '' : '+' }}
                                            {{ $subject['mark'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ changeStudentMarkFigureToText($subject['mark'], 'krd') }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ changeMarkToGrade($subject['mark'], 'krd') }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                @php
                                    // Calculate how many empty rows are needed to match the course with more subjects
                                    $emptyRowsNeeded = $maxRows - count($subjects);
                                @endphp

                                @for ($i = 0; $i < $emptyRowsNeeded; $i++)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endfor
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                @endforeach

                @if (count($courses) == 2)
                    </div>
                @endif
            @endforeach

        </section>

        @php
            $totalSpace += count($notes) * $noteSpace + $otherMargin;
            $signatureMargin = 59 - $totalSpace;
        @endphp

        <section class="notes container">
            <div>

                <h3>تێبینی</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <pre>پله‌: 50-59 په‌سه‌ند     60-69 ناڤنجی     70-79 باش     80-89 زۆر باش     90-100 هه‌ره‌ باش</pre>
                    </li>
                    @foreach ($notes as $note)
                        <li>{{ $note }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="qrCode">
                <div id="qrcode">

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="avgMarks container">

            <h3>تێکرا هوسا دهێتە دەرئێخستن:</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>ساڵا ئێکێ 10٪</div>
                    <div>ساڵا دووێ 20٪</div>
                    <div>ساڵا سیێ 30٪</div>
                    <div>ساڵا چوارێ 40٪</div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </section>

        {{var_dump($signatureMargin)}}

        <section style="margin-top: {{$signatureMargin}}cm;" class="signature container">

            <div>
                <h2>پ.هـ.د. نه‌به‌ز ابراهیم محمد</h2>
                <p>هاریكارێ سه‌رۆكێ زانكویێ بۆ كاروبارێن قوتابیان</p>
            </div>

            <div>
                <h2>ديار هاشم مالو</h2>
                <p>توماركارێ زانكویێ</p>
            </div>

        </section>

        <footer>

            <div>reg@uod.ac</div>

            <div>www.uod.ac</div>

        </footer>

        <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/logo1.png') }}" alt="" class="watermark">


    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/qr-code-styling@1.5.0/lib/qr-code-styling.js"></script>
    <script>
        const qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({
            width: 120,
            height: 120,
            data: "{{ route('admin.qr', ['token' => $certificate->token]) }}",
            type: "image",
            image: "{{ asset('assets/images/logo.png') }}",
            dotsOptions: {
                color: "#005baa",
                type: "rounded"
            },

            imageOptions: {
                crossOrigin: "anonymous",
                margin: 0,
                imageSize: 0.8
            }
        });

        qrCode.append(document.getElementById("qrcode"));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var replaceDigits = function() {
            var map = ["&#1632;", "&#1633;", "&#1634;", "&#1635;", "&#1636;", "&#1637;", "&#1638;", "&#1639;",
                "&#1640;", "&#1641;"
            ];
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\d(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g, function($0) {
                return map[$0];
            });
        }
        window.onload = replaceDigits;
    </script>
    <script>
        function printSection() {
            const printContents = document.getElementById('printSection').innerHTML;
            const originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        }

        // print button


        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', printSection);

        function printView() {
            window.print();
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>




I tried to make you a snippet but please [edit] and change the php to RENDERED HTML in a [mcve].

HAve a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type

that didnt worked.

both solutions didnt worked for me

"Both solutions?" I did not give any solutions. I asked for you to update your code and then to have a look at last-of-type. Since you did not update or post anything, we have no idea of what you tried.

i dont know much about stackover flow I am sorry brother

So please do what I asked, so we can help you. Click [edit], then scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and change the content of the HTML frame with pure HTML (right click on your rendered page, click "inspect" and copy enough content to show the issue in the snippet
